# Add sperator to Long Variable - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have defined a variable as following:

```
Dim Salary As Long
```

After a few calcution in VBA I get a number usually over 10000 which I show on the screen using

```
 MsgBox(Index)
```

The problem is that is shows the variable as following

100000

Is it possible to add a 1000 seperator as you can do in excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Format function. 
The benefit of this approach is that you can use any standard or custom format defined in your Excel book. For example, to format your number as currency:

```
Dim Salary As Long

Salary = 100000
MsgBox Format(Salary, "Currency")
```

Or, you can define your own custom format:

```
Dim Salary As Long

Salary = 100000
MsgBox Format(Salary, "#,###")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `FormatNumber` function, detailed explanation can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfta99yt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

see code below:

```
Dim Salary As Long

Salary = 100000
MsgBox FormatNumber(Salary, 0, GroupDigits:=vbTrue)
```